# how to TRIM a block on SSD disk?

Tags: c, linux

In a C program, how do I tell the linux kernel to TRIM a block on a SSD disk?
I suppose I have to `open()` the device and `fcntl()` it something, but what?
It needs to be generic (i.e. work with different SSD disks)

Note: there is no ext4 filesystem on the device, just raw data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would send it `IOCATADELETE`. Something like this:

```
//header - may already be defined
#define IOCATADELETE _IOW('a', 104, off_t[2])

//code
int fd = open("/dev/abc", O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
off_t ioarg[2];
ioarg[0] = 0; //block number
ioarg[1] = 0; //size
ioctl(fd, IOCATADELETE, ioarg);
close(fd);
```

Comment: What is that "104"? Is it the number of TRIM command or it consist of multiple numbers?

Comment: Same question, could you explain a little bit about the params in `_IOW`? thanks