# Expected expression before `off_t`

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I am trying to send a trim command using c, i figured out the way to do that based on this answer: [how to TRIM a block on SSD disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017625/how-to-trim-a-block-on-ssd-disk).

To compile the progamme i am using

**gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE MyCode.c**

But i am getting the following error:

> TrimCommandsSenders.c:8:37: error: expected expression before ‘off_t’
>     #define IOCATADELETE _IOW('a', 104, off_t[2])

What i am doing wrong?

Here is the full code i am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


//header - may already be defined
#define IOCATADELETE _IOW('a', 104, off_t[2])

int main(){
    //code
    int fd = open("/dev/nvme0n1", O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
    off_t ioarg[2];
    ioarg[0] = 512; //block number
    ioarg[1] = 512; //size
    ioctl(fd, IOCATADELETE, ioarg);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Taking the comments into consideration i've updated my code to the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


off_t arr[2];
#define IOCATADELETE _IOW('a', 104, arr)

int main(){
    int fd = open("/dev/nvme0n1", O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
    off_t my_ioarg[2];
    my_ioarg[0] = 512; //block number
    my_ioarg[1] = 512; //size
    ioctl(fd, IOCATADELETE, my_ioarg);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Undefined reference to "_IOW"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `off_t` is a type. You must have a variable name there.

Comment: `ioarg` is a macro not a variable name. Change name, I.e. `my_ioarg`.

Comment: @usr2564301 i've taking your suggestion into consideration, but i am still getting an error, could you please take a look to my update.

Comment: @Frankie_C i've updated my code based or your suggestion, but i am still getting an error could you please take a look.

Comment: You have to include the header `/usr/include/asm/ioctl.h`. For more info see http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/fusd/docs/node31.html

Comment: @Frankie_C that's indeed what was missing, please post your comment as an answer and i will accept it as a valid answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error generated by the compiler tells you that the macro `_IOW` is not defined.

This macro, with its relatives for ioctl command numbers generation is defined in the header "/usr/include/asm/ioctl.h".

Include this header to solve the problem.

For more info see http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/fusd/docs/node31.html