# How do I trim a raw device address area in C++?

Tags: c++, solid-state-drive

I am using ‘/dev/nvme1’ as my data path, now I want to tell SSD i don’t need [offset, len] anymore, is there a posix API to do that? To send a trim command to SSD FTL.

Comment: A few seconds of Googling finds the existence of the FITRIM ioctl with a struct fstrim_range parameter. It's unclear whether this is supported by the /dev/nme device, this is something that you will need to discover yourself.

Comment: Found a related thread here, seems work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017625/how-to-trim-a-block-on-ssd-disk

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found a piece of code here:

```
int block_device_discard(int fd, int64_t offset, int64_t len)
{
    uint64_t range[2] = {(uint64_t)offset, (uint64_t)len};
    int ret = ioctl(fd, BLKSECDISCARD, range);
    if (ret < 0) {
        return errno;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if your device is not able to support `BLKSECDISCARD`, the command will return an error.

Not sure if it works yet, will update the result later.

References:

- https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/blkdiscard-blkzeroout-blkdiscardzeroes-blksecdiscard/
- [how to TRIM a block on SSD disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017625/how-to-trim-a-block-on-ssd-disk)
- https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html
- https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch06.pdf

Comment: Is BLKDISCARD not good enough?  BLKSECDISCARD is a secure version of BLKDISCARD.